# Gimp Plugin to batch-export several different color shades

Tags: colors, images, image-manipulation, gimp

I hope someone can give me some info on whether or not a plugin exists for Gimp which will automatically do the following...

I've created an icon which I want to save as several different color shades. Is there a plugin which will allow me to quickly save multiple shades of colors as though tweaking the hue by say 7 steps? In other words, is there a way to quickly save multiple versions of my project as Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo and Violet (Roy G Biv)? Or, should I just adjust the hues myself, adding extra time to the process without the help of automation?

You see, manually changing the hue for one project would not save very much time but for several something that could do so automatically could save quite a bit.

I would also be fine knowing if there's another method or application which I could use to do that as well, but Gimp seems like the logical choice for something like this.

Thank you!

Comment: check out the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate_hue) command. It can change hues.

Comment: Thank you, that's not quite as easy as I was hoping it would be, but helpful nonetheless.